# Is there any way to stop Apple OS' native styling on form fields, scrollbars, etc?

Tags: css, ios, macos, focus, native

1. Is there a way, using either CSS or JavaScript, to get rid of the native Apple styling applied to focused DOM elements (e.g. the blue glow) in OS X or iOS)?

   I've checked around online and I can't find anything relating to this subject. I'm about ready to give up hope on this, because I'm thinking since it's part of the OS itself (not just in the browsers) that it can't really be overwritten or avoided in any way.
2. I'm also interested in restyling Apple OS browsers' native scrollbars without using Javascript replacements, but with a solution that will work in all browsers. I'm vagely convinced that it's the same problem (part of the OS itself and thus not able to be styled by the browser) but I just thought I'd check.

   Alternatively, I could use the `-webkit-scrollbar` pseudo elements CSS offers, but that'll only work in Chrome, Safari, and other webkit browsers, right?

Thanks for any help! <3

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457849/how-do-i-disable-the-highlight-border-on-an-html-input-text-element? Also, have you tried any CSS resets?

Comment: I had not seen that post. Thanks a bunch. `outline:none;` works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `outline:none;` on the element in question works great.

For more info, see the question " [How to remove the border highlight on an input text element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457849/how-do-i-disable-the-highlight-border-on-an-html-input-text-element) " as posted by the user j08691 in the comments on my question.