# safari show placeholder on focus

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I want a placeholder when the element is focussed on, on a reload.

It seems to work in Firefox and Chrome but it doesn't work in Safari.

After some googling I found that placeholder gets removed when an input element is focussed in Safari and in Mac.

http://jsbin.com/iqofuh/1/edit

when I click this input element (ie focus) the placeholder gets disappeared in safari and in all Mac browsers(ie chrome,firefox,safari) but it works great in other browsers (ie chrome,ff latest ver)

According to w3c schools

The hint is displayed in the input field when it is empty, and disappears when the field gets focus.

how to overide this default behaviour

Comment: Can you share your code and add some more details? It's a really vague question right now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457849/how-do-i-disable-the-highlight-border-on-an-html-input-text-element

Comment: Unless you write your own replacement, you are stuck with what the browser gives you.

Comment: @AlonPini How does that even relate?

Comment: what version of browsers and Mac do yo use? it seems working on all browsers of my Mac OS 10.8.2