# jQuery UI Slider Handle blue border when 'focus'ed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm restyling the jQuery UI Slider widget by overriding the CSS classes provided by jQuery UI. I cant seem to get the blue border that shows up around the handle when I click on the handle to disappear.

It looks like so: [image: slider handle]

Any suggestions on how I could remove that with css?

Comment: I'm guessing that's the outline ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That blue border is chrome specific, firefox doesn't show it. Chrome adds the border to links. Because the button is a link you are seeing the border.

[How to remove the border highlight on an input text element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457849/how-do-i-disable-the-highlight-border-on-an-html-input-text-element)

Answer (score 5):

try

```
outline: 0 none !important;
```

on the input style

Answer (score 0):

Override it using !important after the attribute value in css.