# How can I stop my browser setting outline on buttons?

Tags: html, css

I have tried this in the CSS:

```
*:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

However it seems not to work in all cases. The only sure way I was able to do this was to set the `outline: 0;` as an inline style on a button.

Is there something I am missing?

How can I set this globally in a CSS?

Comment: Try `:active` as well. And try `!important`.

Comment: Are you using a `<button>` ?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457849/how-do-i-disable-the-default-border-highlight-on-an-html-input-text-element) of any help? Or what do you mean by “seems not to work in _all cases_”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a click is not **:focus**, but **:active**

in generally, you can do:

```
* {
    outline: none; 
}
```