# How to get rid of the input glow in Bootstrap SASS with Chrome/Firefox?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I am trying to extend Bootstrap. I do not want to touch any of the Bootstrap core files, so I have created my own `styles.scss` and in there I have the following:

```
@import "custom/variables";

@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";

@import "custom/modular-styles";
```

In `_variables.scss` I am overwriting some of the variables (e.g. getting rid of rounded corners).

In `_modular-styles.scss` I call various other SASS partials that I want to customise (e.g. `_forms.scss`).

In `_forms.scss` here is what I've done:

```
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: $input-height-base;
    padding: $padding-base-vertical $padding-base-horizontal;
    font-size: $font-size-base;
    line-height: $line-height-base;
    color: $input-color;
    background-color: $input-bg;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid $input-border;
    border-radius: $input-border-radius;
    box-shadow: none; // this use to be @include box-shadow(inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075));
    @include transition(border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s);
    outline: none; // this use to be @include form-control-focus;

    @include placeholder;

    &::-ms-expand {
        border: 0;
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    &:focus {
        outline: none;
    }

    &[disabled],
    &[readonly],
    fieldset[disabled] & {
        background-color: $input-bg-disabled;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    &[disabled],
    fieldset[disabled] & {
        cursor: $cursor-disabled;
    }
}
```

Shouldn't that work? Yet I am still seeing the outline glow when an input is on `:focus`

Comment: I would start by asking whether you really should?  I know it's nice for you to have your website look consistent on all browsers, but this isn't good for the user.  A user who always uses Chrome should get a consistent "Chromey" experience across all sites.

Comment: @RikLewis Regardless, Bootstrap already modifies the default behavior of textboxes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The glow on focus in Bootstrap is given by a box-shadow on **:focus**, like this:

```
.form-control:focus {
    border-color: #66afe9;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6);
}
```

If you want to modify your focus styles add sth like this:

```
.form-control {

  &:focus {
     box-shadow: none;
     /* your new styles */
  }

}
```

Comment: Here a sample with Bootstrap v.3.3.7 to show that it works: http://www.bootply.com/g8AKj3OnTb

Comment: then it must be SASS ordering! :( Can you see an issue? From what I can tell, my `_forms.scss` is loaded **after** the bootstrap stuff

Comment: Do you have a URL to look at?

Comment: Nope, this is all local, I am trying to learn how to work with Boostrap SASS

Comment: Use a new file for modifying BS. Call that custom file after Bootstrap. Overwrite both, -webkit-box-shadow and box-shadow there.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by overriding the sass variables:

```
$input-box-shadow: none;
$input-focus-box-shadow: none;
$input-btn-focus-box-shadow: none;
```

And in case that doesn't do the trick (I've seen some weird behaviors with files ordering):

```
.form-control {
  &:focus {
    box-shadow: none !important;
  }
}
```

Just a hint, but make sure you've imported Bootstrap only once. Once I had forgotten to remove it from my `angular.json` (former `angular-cli.json`) and that caused conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following CSS:

```
textarea:hover, 
input:hover, 
textarea:active, 
input:active, 
textarea:focus, 
input:focus,
button:focus,
button:active,
button:hover,
label:focus,
.btn:active,
.btn.active
{
    outline: none !important;
    border: none !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Yep I think I am. My `_forums.scss` sits within `_modular-styles.scss` and that is loaded **after** I load the Bootstrap stuff

Answer (score 0):

From what I recall, you need to override the outline in the `:focus` pseudo class, not just the main css class

```
.form-control {
    ...
    &:focus {
        outline: none;
    }
}
```

See: [How to remove the border highlight on an input text element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457849/how-to-remove-the-border-highlight-on-an-input-text-element)

Comment: Thanks, I just added that, but I still get the glow!

Comment: Are you able to paste your full (compiled) css? This example works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/50mjut5d/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following css

```
.form-control:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Explanation: In Bootstrap, the value of `box-shadow` changed when the input tag is focused, so the `transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out`  worked.

Hope it helps.