# I hate this kind of border in search bar. Why does it appear?

Tags: css, border

When I click in the search bar, a blue border appears. Why does this happen in several cases?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EO3c.jpg

Comment: It's the CSS outline property. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397113/how-to-remove-border-outline-around-text-input-boxes-chrome?rq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457849/how-to-remove-the-border-highlight-on-an-input-text-element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the border highlight on an input text element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457849/how-to-remove-the-border-highlight-on-an-input-text-element)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate; that question was about removing it from a website created by the poster asking the question, while this question seems to be about a situation where the poster is viewing the website rather than creating it.  I'd guess the poster is also newer to computing than most people on StackOverflow, but I am a firm believer in the importance of helping everyone, regardless of their experience level.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Because the website, or possibly your browser, was set up (using css) to make it appear, because most people prefer it that way so they know which box is active.

Depending on your browser, it is probably possible to set it so that this doesn't happen (from your question, I presume that you are asking about other people's websites, not your own), though I can't give you tips on that without knowing what browser you are using.