# How to hide borders of <input> & <button> tags?

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML:- `<input>` & `<button>`

You may have noticed when a user clicks on it (`:focus`) in mobile browsers (or others), a deep yellow border appears on the screen!

[image: Deep Yellow Borders]

I want to hide those borders using CSS or Javascript.
If I use `border: none;` code, it hides the black borders, not those deep yellow colored borders!

So how can I hide those borders?

Comment: Have you tried `outline:none;`?

Comment: I think this post is exactly what you looking for "[How to remove the border highlight on an input text element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457849/how-to-remove-the-border-highlight-on-an-input-text-element)"

Comment: [don't use outline:none](http://www.outlinenone.com/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the border highlight on an input text element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457849/how-to-remove-the-border-highlight-on-an-input-text-element)

Comment: @l haz kode its ok... I got solution of it in morning... But still I'm getting answers & comments.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
input:focus {
    outline:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css

```
input:focus, button:focus { 
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

**CSS**

```
<style>
  #inputId:focus OR input[type=text]:focus
   {
     outline: none !important;
     border:none !important;;
     box-shadow: none !important;;
                OR
     border:1px black solid;
   }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="inputId">
```

Comment: What is the role of `!important`?

Comment: I've not included `!important`, but what will happen if I include it?

Comment: @user8427031, It helps to override an exiting style.

Comment: @user8427031, If it helps u means then accept my ans

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code.

```
input:focus{
  outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
input[type=text],button{
  border: none;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<button type="button" >Ok</button>
```