# How do you remove the blue border of an image map?

Tags: html, css

The landing page is a static background image and I created a clickable area with image map. The problem is that a blue border (see image below) shows up when you click on the area. I want to remove that border however nothing seems to be working.

```
<div class="fixed-background" >
<img src="picture.svg" usemap="#image-map">
</div>

<map name="image-map">
<area href="target.org" coords="300,1000,30,1100" shape="rect">
</map>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have any css we can look at?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45860781/8157693

Answer (score 3):

That's looks like the `focus` state.

You can avoid that defining

```
*:focus { outline: none; }
```

but on the other hand, the visible focus is important for people who don't use a mouse or touchpad, i.e. who only use the keyboard for moving around at a page (keyword ACCESSIBILITY), so you should really consider leaving it as is (maybe only change the outline color to fit better in your page)

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the object's `outline`.

If you specify `outline: none` in the CSS for an object, it removes the blue glow that you see when an element is selected in the browser.

Comment: `outline:none` by itself is not a good solution. There's a reason why the outline is there.

Comment: it depends what you want to achieve.  This isn't an input field, and there is little to be gained from retaining the outline for an image map.

Comment: Not trying to achieve anything. When you remove the default browser outline and don't provide an alternative, the website becomes inaccessible/less accessible to someone not using a mouse.

Comment: That's down to the discretion of the developer.  I'm not so sure you'd want to produce an elaborate solution that isn't just `outline: none`, just so people could (somehow) choose to use a clickable image map without a mouse.  It's better to solve the problem, rather than issues that don't or won't exist.