# How to remove blue background of inputs (radio, select and checkbox) on mobile devices?

Tags: html, css, mobile

I tried to remove the focus background when the user clicks on the input (radio, checkbox or select) but it not works. These are the styles that I put on the element:

```
    .form-holder input[type="radio"]:focus, .form-holder input[type="checkbox"]:focus {
     background: transparent;
     box-shadow: none;
     outline: 0!important;
     outline: none!important;
     -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent!important;
    }
```

[Test image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9pfJ.png)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cguLtzhu/1/)

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried with outline-width: 0, as suggested here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457849/how-to-remove-the-border-highlight-on-an-input-text-element

Comment: is this code inside the media query?

Comment: Hi sissy, thanks for your answer. I tried to add it to, but still not working. The blue background stills showing.

Comment: Hi ShadowFiend. Yes, it is inside in @media (max-width: 767px) query, but not working.

Comment: Hi, I found the solution. Because the input is inside the label is necessary to put those styles on the label, because the label is doing that interaction. Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Because the input is inside the label is necessary to put those styles on the label, because the label is doing that interaction. Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

```
.form-holder input[type="radio"]:focus, .form-holder input[type="checkbox"]:focus {
     background: transparent;
     box-shadow: none;
outline: none;
  outline-width: 0;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi Alias Varghese. Thanks for your comment. I tried to put the outline-width: 0, but still not working, I'm still trying to find the issue.

Comment: Can you add your html in JSFIddle?

Comment: I think you have put it inside button or something

Comment: Hi, I added the sample code on a JSFiddle, there it is: https://jsfiddle.net/cguLtzhu/1/

Comment: try outline-color:transparent;

Comment: Hi Alias Varghese, I tried it to but on mobile still appears the blue background

Comment: Hi, I found the solution. Because the input is inside the label is necessary to put those styles on the label, because the label is doing that interaction. Thanks for all.