# How to remove outline in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to remove textbox outline in **bootstrap 4** but its not working. How can I remove this line?

[image]

**CSS**

```
#content #main-content input[type=text]{
   border: 0;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   height: 40px;
   padding-left: 10px;
   outline: 0;
 }
```

**html**

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="title">Title <span>*</span></label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Enter Title">
</div>
```

Comment: As far I know this does not come in bootstrap4.....share working fiddle or codepen link...

Comment: I have download customize css from https://bootswatch.com/materia/

Comment: It looks like you're using a theme. You have to override that theme. Which means you must write CSS rules that either apply later, having same selectors as the theme, or write CSS rules with stronger selectors than the theme, for the properties you want to change. Without a [mcve] nobody can help you.

Comment: Not sure if this is of relevance anymore but I had the same kind of issue with removing the border of the button as the hamburger menu when clicked in bootstrap 4.5...tried everything described here, adjusting variables etc... however I managed to get the job done by setting the following in my own css (after loading bootstrap of course) -> button:focus {   outline: 0px none;  outline: 0px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color; }

Comment: i just simple put these two properties to none
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The theme you're using sets `box-shadow` to `inset 0 -2px 0 #2196F3` on `focus`.

You need to override it, but not with `none`, because that would just remove it. You probably want it to remain at same value like when it's not focused. In short, you need this:

```
textarea:focus, 
textarea.form-control:focus, 
input.form-control:focus, 
input[type=text]:focus, 
input[type=password]:focus, 
input[type=email]:focus, 
input[type=number]:focus, 
[type=text].form-control:focus, 
[type=password].form-control:focus, 
[type=email].form-control:focus, 
[type=tel].form-control:focus, 
[contenteditable].form-control:focus {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 #ddd;
}
```

Also note you need to load this CSS after Bootstrap CSS and the theme you're loading.

Answer (score 127):

You can add the `shadow-none` Bootstrap class to remove the focus outline:

```
<div class="form-label-group">
  <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control shadow-none" placeholder="Password" required>
  <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
</div>
```

Comment: easy solution still working in 2019 :) I used it for the button which is part of the bootstrap 4 dropdown

Comment: This is a great elegant solution that also works for buttons.  Why isn't this the accepted answer?

Comment: Not much of a "me too" guy, but this works great. Never knew the class existed. Tidbits like this are shared with my students :)

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Woody. I didn't know it existed either, until one day I figured there had to be a better way and I went digging around the Bootstrap sources. Too bad it's not documented better.

Comment: Worked for me in Bootstrap 5, 2022.

Comment: Its bootstrap 5 and it works like hell :)

Answer (score 29):

As the accepted answer works it isn't the best option.
You could simply override the input/button outline by editing the variables. (As the question specifically asks for bootstrap 4)

If you override the Bootstrap 4 variables [like so](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/options/#customizing-variables). You could use the following code to disable **all** focus outlines:

```
$input-btn-focus-box-shadow: none;
$input-btn-focus-width: 0;
```

For only disabling the button focus outline use the follow code:

```
$btn-focus-box-shadow: none;
```

This you could also be done for indicators, select, dropdown etc. Just search the default [variables list of bootstrap 4](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_variables.scss)

---

#### EDIT

Also works for v5: [Github variables](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v5.0.0-alpha1/scss/_variables.scss#L537-L540)

Even though you can disable the focus outline, it isn't a best practice. Conform the web accessibility keyboard standards a site should be useable by tabbing. By disabling the CSS you disable this functionality.

To separate these users there is a new pseudo class: `:focus-visible` which you can use however [it's not compatible](https://caniuse.com/css-focus-visible) everywhere yet. [Chromium changelog](https://blog.chromium.org/2020/09/giving-users-and-developers-more.html)

Comment: Thanks. The first one works, but only for inputs. For buttons, I've found $input-btn-focus-width, which should be set to 0. Just in case someone finds this answer.

Comment: @soeik your comment saved my life!

Answer (score 4):

You have to remove your `box-shadow` on `input:focus`.

Write this css in your custom css file below the bootstrap css to override. It will be good practice if you use your custom parent class.

```
.parent-class .form-group input[type=text]:focus,
.parent-class .form-group [type=text].form-control:focus, {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is better and shorter:

```
input[type="text"], textarea {
              outline: none;
              box-shadow:none !important;
              border:1px solid #ccc !important;
                                                 }
```

Answer (score 2):

A very simple solution would be like this,

```
form .form-control:focus{
  border-color: #0d6efd;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

we overwrite the .form-control bootstrap class.
I was facing the same issue I solved it using this trick in such a way that we don't have to think about importing CSS after bootstrap or something like that.
Note: #0d6efd is the color I wanted to give to my input element when it gets focused.

Answer (score 2):

Using a *box-shadow* will not completely hide the outline in the button, and **it doesn't work on inputs, text-boxes and other form controls**...
Using the `shadow-none` will may have a slight and thin border, but it is much better than the former solution...Here's the code if you need assistance:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form action="/search" method="get">
  <center class="container">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">

      <input type="text" class="form-control shadow-none" placeholder="Search the web" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required name="q" autocomplete="off">
      <input type="submit" class="btn input-group-text shadow-none" id="basic-addon1" value="search">
    </div>
  </center>
</form>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code just worked for me now and I sure do hope it helps somebody else too ..

```
.form-group input:focus{
     outline:0px !important; 
     box-shadow: none !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are theming in scss

```
$input-btn-focus-box-shadow: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

This one line, taken from @tao works when adding a css style:

The inset, however, should be zero. (It will create a weird line in the latest Bootstrap 4.)

```
<input type="radio" style="box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 #ddd;">
```

'shadow-none' is not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add
box-shadow: none
on focus event in CSS.
For example.

```
.box_style:focus{
       border:none;
       box-shadow:none;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `!important` property in any css code. That will not overwrite other css.
Try this:

```
//for normal text box
input[type=text]{
   border: 0 !important;
   height: 40px;
   padding-left: 10px;
   outline: 0 !important;
}
//for selected/active text box
input[type=text]:focus{
   border: 0 !important;
   outline: 0 !important;
}
//for hovered text box
input[type=text]:hover{
   border: 0 !important;
   outline: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending literal hours digging into developer tools trying to fix the same issue for Bootstrap 5.2 accordion buttons, including at least one trying to set `$accordion-button-focus-box-shadow: none` before realising it wasn't going to work, I eventually fixed this with:

```
$accordion-button-focus-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 var(--bs-border-color);
```

This essentially takes the approach of *tao*'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48484022/1191147) - setting the box-shadow as close as possible to the current setting instead of disabling it entirely - and applies it to SASS so it can be done at build time rather than trying to override it in the CSS.

It also makes the change application-wide so is a *lot* faster and lighter than setting `shadow-none` on every element that has a box shadow.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I see from your css, you set the border to 0 then again to 1. Replace it as below

```
#content #main-content input[type=text]{
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border: 0;
 height: 40px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this on `input: focus`

```
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 0px;
background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
```