# Remove outline of input field with "form control"

Tags: html, css, input, outline

I have an input field as shown below. And in the class name I have it as `form-control`

```
<input ref={englishTypeRef} className="form-control p-3 settings-input" placeholder={dbData ? dbData.englishType : null}/>
```

Whenever I focus into this field, I get a blue outline around the borders.
So In my settings-input I use `outline:none`

```
.settings-input{
    ...
}
.settings-input:focus {
    outline:none;
}
```

But the blue border on focus remains the same. How can I remove this?

Bootstrap: `"bootstrap": "^5.0.2"`
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try overriding form-control styles like this:

```
.form-control:focus {
  border-color: #ced4da; /* default B5 color or set your own color*/
  border: none !important; /* if you want to remove borders at all*/
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Comment: yes, I am using bootstrap. Also, putting .form-control:focus removes my styles when I click on the input field.

Comment: Okay, if it is bootstrap 4. This thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48483925/how-to-remove-outline-in-bootstrap-4

Comment: updated the answer, is it working for you now? If not, what bootstrap version are you using? can you attach an image? Thanks

Comment: Sadly, your example did not work. And I updated my post with the needed info.

Comment: I see... Bootstrap 5 sets border color for focus state. Can you try the updated answer? :)

Comment: HAHA! That works fabulouslyyy. Thank you so much!