# How do I remove the blue border around the input element in bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, forms, input, bootstrap-4

[image]

Whenever I click on the input field, a blue border appears around it. How do I remove or change this?

```
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" 
           aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
           <div class="input-group-append">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary mb- 2">Subscribe</button>
            </div>
          </div>
```

For this code, I wrote the following code, but instead of the blue border around it, it removed the border inside the input.

```
.input:focus {
outline: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean input rather than .input in the CSS you have shown?

Comment: checks here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68461311/remove-outline-of-input-field-with-form-control

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `box-shadow` property to none like:

```
.form-control:focus {
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #80bdff;
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: none!important;
}
```

remove the `border color` property too if you don't need it.