# How to give the search button desired on-click effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

This is what I made:

[image]

And this is what I want:

[image]

Both search bars are on on-click states
I can't find a way using bootstrap, CSS, JS,

how can I implement this feature.

**Code:**

```css
.loc-icon{
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 15px
}

.loc-input{
  border: none;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.loc-submit{
    background-color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group mb-3 loc-bar">
    <span class="input-group-text loc-icon" id="inputGroup-sizing-default"><img src="Images/place.png" alt=""></span> <!-- location icon -->
    <input type="text" class="form-control loc-input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" placeholder="Enter your location">
    <button class="loc-submit " type="submit" name="button"><a href="/"><img src="Images/right-arrow.png" alt=""></a></button>
  </div>
```

Pls help me!!

Thankyou Amazing ppl..

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong what you want is to remove the focus outline and you can achieve that by using `shadow-none` class [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54639265/8862498)

Comment: Thank you,  Along with this I also want to know how can I add the button showing "Use current location"(u can see it in the 2nd image) when the the search bar is in on-click state. I'm only talking wrt front-end

Comment: there is a good example for that in this link : https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/check+if+input+is+focused