# React-Select Remove focus border

Tags: css, reactjs, react-select

i cant figure out how do i remove border or outline ( not sure which one it is ) from react select, when its focused.

Uploaded image for reference. I have no border by default.[image]

```
customStyle = {      
        control: provided => ({
            ...provided,           
            height: 10,
            width: 300,
            padding: 10,
            margin: 0,
            marginLeft: 0,
            border: "0px solid black",
            fontSize: 13,
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            outline: 'none'            
        })
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Please add a relevant code snippet. There are already tons of examples of how to hide a border or outline https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457849/how-to-remove-the-border-highlight-on-an-input-text-element

Comment: @SuperDJ There is realy no relevant code snippet for this i think. I need help removing border / outline specificaly from focused state of React-Select component. I have no idea what to select or how to adjust style options. I have went over all documenation and all topics i could find on this. But this is definitely not question about removing simple outline/border from normal component.

Comment: People, don't do this please—you'll end up excluding people relying on visual focus cues when using your interfaces (e.g. using keyboard nav). The only time you should do this is when you want to _replace_ the focus styles with your own

Answer (score 131, accepted):

### React-select v3

```
const style = {
  control: base => ({
    ...base,
    border: 0,
    // This line disable the blue border
    boxShadow: 'none'
  })
};
```

Here a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-v2-custom-styles-9703u)

### React-select v2

To reset border when `Select` is focused you have two solutions:

1. Use the `state`

   ```
   control: (base, state) => ({
       ...base,
       border: state.isFocused ? 0 : 0,
       // This line disable the blue border
       boxShadow: state.isFocused ? 0 : 0,
       '&:hover': {
          border: state.isFocused ? 0 : 0
       }
   })
   ```
2. Use `!important` (this one works but I recommend to use the first
   solution, `!important` is never a good thing to employ)

   ```
   control: base => ({
      ...base,
      border: '0 !important',
      // This line disable the blue border
      boxShadow: '0 !important',
      '&:hover': {
          border: '0 !important'
       }
   })
   ```

Don't forgot to reset the `boxShadow` (blue border) that you get.

Here a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/yqww865531).

Comment: This solution is a bit excessive (although working), it is sufficient to use `boxShadow: 'none'`

Comment: @AlexDobrushskiy depending your version of react-select, removing just the box-shadow with none is not working (specially in early v2)

Comment: @AlexDobrushskiy I have edited my answer for newer version of `react-select`

Comment: Would it make sense to add a disclaimer at the beginning of this answer to tell developers they shouldn't do this, unless they're replacing the focus styles by their own? This is an accessibility issue

Answer (score 33):

This worked for me:

```
control: (base, state) => ({
    ...base,
    border: '1px solid black',
    boxShadow: 'none',
    '&:hover': {
        border: '1px solid black',
    }
})
```

This will ensure the border remains when inactive, hovered or active but there is no blue box shadow.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone using `react-select` with `@tailwindcss/forms`, the dreaded blue line aka box-shadow on the input is introduced by the forms plugin.
You need to pass `strategy: class` to the forms plugin in `tailwind.config.js` file.

```js
plugins: [
  ...
  require('@tailwindcss/forms')({
    strategy: 'class',
  }),
]
```

More on this here:  https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-forms#using-only-global-styles-or-only-classes

Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75541836/5712125

Comment: thank heavens for you, @Akshay. This is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 6):

This one is definitely working:

```
const style = {
    control: (base) => ({
      ...base,
      boxShadow: "none"
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have tried a lot! and finally This one worked for me.

```
control: (provided) => ({
...provided,
border: 0,
outline: '1px solid white',
```

}),

Answer (score 1):

This removes the thickness of the box-shadow, and removes the blue from the border.

```
const controlStyle = base => ({
    ...base, 
    boxShadow: "none", 
    borderColor: "#cccccc",
    "&:hover": {
        borderColor: "#cccccc"
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Lord in heaven we needed:

```js
import AsyncSelect from "react-select/async";

<AsyncSelect
  onChange={(v) => {
    props.onChange(v);
  }}
  
  {/* ... */}
  
  styles={{
    control: (base, state) => ({
      ...base,
      "*": {
        boxShadow: "none !important",
      },
    })
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach of Akshay Kumar's awnser that worked for me:

```
input[id^="react-select-"] {
  @apply focus:outline-none focus:border-transparent focus:ring-0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than remove it you might want to change the color this is how you might go about this V3 ReactSelect

```
      styles = {{
        control: (baseStyles, state) => ({
          ...baseStyles,
          borderColor: state.isFocused ? 'limegreen' : 'red',
          boxShadow: state.isFocused ? '0 0 0px 4px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)' : 'none',
          '&:hover': {
            borderColor: 'limegreen'
          }
        }),
      }}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```js
styles={{
            control: (base) => ({
              ...base,
              zIndex: 9999,
              border: "1.5px solid #c9ccd0",
              boxShadow: "none !important",
              "*": {
                boxShadow: "none !important",
              },
              "&:hover": {
                border: "1.5px solid #7e22ce !important",
              },
            }),
          }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 styles={{
                          control: (base, state) => ({
                            ...base,
                            border: "none",
                            boxShadow: "none",
                            "&:hover": {
                              border: "none",
                            },
                          }),
                        }}
```