# how to remove the outline and box shadow on input tag in react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I want to remove the blue outline and box-shadow when the input tag is active. [image: Input image]

Comment: "the blue outline" you mean the cursor?

Comment: the cursor which is black in color is within the blue outlined box

Answer (score 1):

The box shadow is introduced by `@tailwindcss/forms` plugin.
Default strategy for the forms plugin is to globally apply styles on form elements.

You can change this by specifying a different strategy for the plugin in `tailwind.config.js` file.

```js
plugins: [
  ...
  require('@tailwindcss/forms')({
    strategy: 'class',
  }),
]
```

But now you would have to apply `form-[inputType]` classes on all form elements you want styled with `@tailwindcss/forms` plugin.

Here's more on this: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-forms#using-only-global-styles-or-only-classes

Comment: This should be marked as the accepted response. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I could do this with: 
 input[id^="react-select-"] {
    @apply focus:outline-none focus:border-transparent focus:ring-0;
  }

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass custom styles prop.

Something like this

```
const customStyles = {
    control: (base, state) => ({
      ...base,
      height: "100%",
      minHeight: "100%",
      border: 0,
      boxShadow: "none",
    }),
    dropdownIndicator: (base, state) => {
      return {
        ...base,
      };
    },
    placeholder: (base, state) => ({
      ...base,
    }),
    singleValue: (base, state) => ({
      ...base,
    }),
    option: (base, state) => ({
      ...base,
    }),
  };


return (
  <Select 
   //REST OF YOUR PROPS
   styles={customStyles}
   isSearchable={false}   //This gets rid of the default cursor
  /> 
)
```

Try playing around with the `customStyles` object to style it further :)

Comment: I did that but we don't have any key for the input tag

Comment: Create a minimum reproducible question in code sandbox , I will edit it for you :)

Answer (score 0):

The default styles are derived from a theme object, which you can mutate like styles.

The theme object is available for the styles functions as well.

```
    <Select
        label="Single select"
        options={user}
        theme={theme => ({
          ...theme,
          borderRadius: 'none',
          colors: {
            ...theme.colors,
            primary25: 'primary',
            primary: 'neutral5',
          },
        })}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

const style = {
control: base => ({
...base,
border: 0,
boxShadow: 'none'
})
};

Comment: This does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but the blue outline is a drop-shadow on the input field itself (at least was in my case), I ended up just adding a custom class to the select field like

```
<ReactSelect
    title = { __( 'Title', 'lang' ) }
    className = { 'your-custom-class' }
...
```

and then styling it out with

```
.your-custom-class input {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach of Akshay Kumar's awnser that worked for me (tailwind):

```
input[id^="react-select-"] {
  @apply focus:outline-none focus:border-transparent focus:ring-0;
}
```