# changing the color of the top and bottom parts of select dropdown

Tags: html, css, select, react-select

What's the part of the React select dropdown called (the top white curvy part above the first option, in this case option `0`)? Is there a way to change the color of that or remove it? There's also one at the bottom of the dropdown. Not sure if that's considered a border

[image]

```
 <ReactSelect
              options={options}
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
              value={selectOption}
              className="text-black"
            />
```

another example is here, screenshot taken from react select dropdown https://react-select.com/home, there's that thin white part at the top of the dropdown, right above the first option `Ocean`

[image]

another example from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select, there's that thin part above where it says `Please select an option` and below Goldfish

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a code example? My first guess would be that it's a border or an outline, but it's hard to tell based on a screenshot

Comment: added, it's kinda unrelated to the code, i'm not sure how else to describe other than the screenshot

Comment: If you are using bootstrap, border classes:  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/

Comment: Where is `ReactSelect` coming from?

Comment: There was already a solution for this [Check This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52614304/react-select-remove-focus-border)

Comment: this is for the dropdown part, not the input part, react select is just what i'm happen to be using, i added another screenshot