# How to remove grey highlight on Safari desktop?

Tags: css, safari, highlight, desktop

So I have buttons/tabs/links/text that appear fine everywhere except on Safari desktop. They have a grey hightlight. I read many questions before posting mine, and I couldn't find a fix to my problem.

[image]

I've tried to put that

```
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

everywhere I could think of, but the grey highlight do not disappear.

The website is live, might be easier like that to have access to the code.
uhearst.ca/ouac

Thank you!

PS: it should look like that

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457849/how-to-remove-the-border-highlight-on-an-input-text-element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the border highlight on an input text element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457849/how-to-remove-the-border-highlight-on-an-input-text-element)

Comment: http://outlinenone.com/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
.tab button {
  background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: @mpladesigner You're welcome, could you accept the answer. Thanks.