# How to disable input button's default style?

Tags: css

[image]

when the input button is focused, it's border color will be bule.How to disable it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the border highlight on an input text element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457849/how-to-remove-the-border-highlight-on-an-input-text-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `:focus` [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) combined with the `outline: 0;` [property and value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline).

```css
.input2:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input class="input2" type="text">
```

As a best practice, you should not remove the focus indicator unless you are adding one of your own back in. In this case, one that wraps the entire search box. Here is an [article](https://hackernoon.com/removing-that-ugly-focus-ring-and-keeping-it-too-6c8727fefcd2) on the topic.

You might also be interested in the new `:focus-visible` [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-visible) that can help prevent focus from showing on keyboard clicks of some components such as buttons. Unfortunately, `:focus-visible` has limited [support](https://caniuse.com/#search=%3Afocus-visible) right now but should see more browsers turning it on in 2019.