# Rounded input text box, but square selection box appears

Tags: html, css

[text input selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0nxz.gif)(.gif)

I make a text input box have rounded corners, but when I select it to type, a square selection box surrounds it.

How can I make the selection box to have rounded corners as well? Or is there a way to disable the square selection box that appears?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you please put the code that makes the text box?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the border highlight on an input text element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457849/how-to-remove-the-border-highlight-on-an-input-text-element)

Comment: yes, thank you. I wasn't able to find forum threads that existed on this topic as I used the wrong keywords to look for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's showing up is the outline. The `outline` is a CSS property. It appears on elements that are in focus (such as an `input` being typed in). You can remove it if you like, but **make sure** to use `border`, `box-shadow`, or something else when it is focused. Adding a focus indicator is important for web accessibility. Here's an example of what is happening and a possible solution:

```css
input {
border-radius: 10px;
}

#input2 {
  outline: none;
}

#input2:focus {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<input id="input1">
<br><br>
<input id="input2">
```

This substitutes `border` for `outline`. It's still accessible, but `border` respects `border-radius`.

Comment: thanks for your help, your comment on "border, box-shadow" is a good point. I've only started learning, and did not know about the focus indicator, thanks for pointing that out to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
input {
  border-radius: 5px;
 }
input:focus {
  outline-width: 0;
 }
```

```html
<input>
```

As @AlexH pointed out, you could also add other things to the `input: focus` to make it more accessible.

Example:

```css
input{
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
}

input:focus{
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input>
```

Making it clean:

You can use @keyframes for an even better transition, and transitions, as they last longer, might be a more effective tool for accessibility (in my experience)

```css
input{
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

input:focus{
  animation: input 0.5s forwards;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 2px solid #55555;
  outline: none;
}

@keyframes input{
  from{
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  to{
    border-radius: 9px;
    border: 1px solid #555555;
  }
}
```

```html
<input>
```

Comment: Removing `outline` and not adding a focus indicator is bad for accessiblity.

Comment: @AlexH what do you mean. It answered the question. This was the exact answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457849/how-to-remove-the-border-highlight-on-an-input-text-element)

Comment: Someone who uses the tab key to navigate a page (potentially because of a vision impairment) would not know where they are. They would have difficulty navigating the page and might get lost.

Comment: @AlexH yes, you could also add a number of other things. All I did was answer the question

Comment: That's correct. But it's important to point out things like this so the OP doesn't unknowingly make a mistake. That's the difference between an answer and a *good* answer--an answer addresses the question, but a good answer addresses the problem. The distinction between problem and question is an important one.

Comment: (Also, [this](https://www.a11yproject.com/posts/2013-01-25-never-remove-css-outlines/) is a link that explains more about outlines and accessibility)

Comment: @AlexH Thank you, I added more to my post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224758/discussion-between-alexh-and-haveproblemseveryday).

Comment: Thank you both so much for your help! I did not even take into account accessibility, and will remember to in the future.