# How can I remove the black outline around my input areas?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I have these black boxes go round the input area on the form I am building. Is there a way I can remove this, I am also using bootstrap not sure if that is affecting it but if there is any ideas. Greatly appreciated! [image: Input area with black box]

```css
.form-input-styling {
  border-radius: 0 2em;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 50%;
  border: none;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #f25b43;
}
```

```html
  <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12"><input class="form-input form-input-styling" type="text" id="fname" name="fname" required placeholder="Name"></div>
            <div class="col-12"><input class="form-input form-input-styling" type="email" id="email" name="email" required placeholder="Email"></div>
            <div class="col-12"><input class="form-input form-input-styling" type="tel" id="phone_num" name="phone_num" placeholder="Phone Number"></div>
            <div class="col-12"><textarea id="text-area" name="textarea" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Enter Your Message Here"></textarea></div>
            <div class="col-12"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think you'll want to reset the border on the `:focus` styles

Comment: Use your browser inspector to find out which CSS rule is setting this border box and then adjust accordinghly. You may need to increase your CSS Specificity for your CSS rule such as `input.form-input-styling`, etc.

Comment: in css:  `outline: none;`

Comment: add this style: `outline: none` to the input, it will work as you are expecting to work

Comment: Definitely don't remove the outline. http://www.outlinenone.com/ https://medium.com/better-programming/a11y-never-remove-the-outlines-ee4efc7a9968

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the border highlight on an input text element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457849/how-to-remove-the-border-highlight-on-an-input-text-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `outline: none;` to your css for the input element.

```
.form-input-styling {
  border-radius: 0 2em;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 50%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #f25b43;
}
```