# How do I remove the default orange highlight around a button onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

[image]

The problem is pretty simple: In my electron application, After I click any of my buttons, by default, I get this orange outline.

How do I change it's colour or remove it?

Comment: did `outline: none` worked??

Comment: outline worked. could you post that as solution

Comment: Glad it worked. Posting it as answer would be redundant as there are multiple questions and similar answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397113/how-to-remove-focus-border-outline-around-text-input-boxes-chrome) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457849/how-to-remove-the-border-highlight-on-an-input-text-element). You can find more details there if you want. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the border highlight on an input text element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457849/how-to-remove-the-border-highlight-on-an-input-text-element)