# how to remove bule outline on focus of input in React typescript

Tags: html, css, typescript, bootstrap-4, react-hooks

Here is my code in input.tsx

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="h-12 px-4 w-full h-12 px-4 placeholder-gray-500 border border-transparent rounded outline-none transition duration-200 text-gray-900 bg-gray-f7 hover:border-gray-400 focus:border-black focus:placeholder-gray-900 mb-10px bg-gray-100   " id="emailAddress" autocomplete="off" name="emailAddress" value="">
```

**"onFocus"** blue outline is coming on my UAT (not in localhost);
i.e:

```css
    input[type=text]:focus {
    outline: 2px solid #2d8cff !important;
    outline-offset: 1px !important;
}
```

I have overrided this CSS with `outline:none !important;` but CSS is not appearing on UAT server.

Comment: the overrided css in app.css is...........input[type=text]:focus {
  outline: 0 !important;
  outline-offset: 0 !important;
}

Comment: Try setting outline, border, and box-shadow all to 0/none, if that doesn't work, when you scroll down in the styles debug menu, do you see anything else when you force the `:focus` element state from the right-hand menu?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `css specificity` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

There might be some other parent element which is causing this.

**Removing outline**

1. [How to remove focus border (outline) around text/input boxes? (Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397113/how-to-remove-focus-border-outline-around-text-input-boxes-chrome)
2. [How to remove the border highlight on an input text element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457849/how-to-remove-the-border-highlight-on-an-input-text-element)

Comment: i have tried these. still the same issue

Comment: Have you check `css specificity`? share your sample working code. and screenshot to answer this